# TypeError: src data type = 17 is not supported

Tags: python, opencv

I'm now in a program try to change pictures from normal to binaryzation.So i use opencv on python, but when i finish my problem in my home carry my code to my office it come up with a unknown error.So i come to here ,looking for help.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
im = Image.open('card.jpg')
img = np.array(im)
if img.ndim == 3:
    img = img[:, :,0]
    plt.gray()
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)


plt.subplot(222)
plt.imshow(thresh1)
plt.show()
```

The traceback is

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:/tensorflow/opencv.py", line 12, in  ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) TypeError: src data type = 17 is not supported

Answer (score 18):

You can find a list of OpenCV types [here](https://gist.github.com/yangcha/38f2fa630e223a8546f9b48ebbb3e61a).

`type = 17` means that your image is a `CV_8SC3`, aka a 3 channel matrix of `char`. However, [`threshold`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57) accepts only

> (single-channel, 8-bit or 32-bit floating point).

which means that the type must be either `CV_8UC1` or `CV_32FC1`.

Check `shape` and `dtype` of your `img`, and adjust `img` as required.