# How to resolve "data type = 19 is not supported" error in python?

Tags: python, ocr

dear.
I am going to get text from image using python ocr.
I hope resolve following error.
I can not solve this error.
code and error is follow.
thanks.

```
    import pytesseract
    from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter
    import cv2
    import numpy as np


    src_path = ""
    def get_string(img_path):

    #read image with opencv
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    #convert to gray
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise
    kernel = np.ones((1,1), np.unicode)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    cv2.imwrite("2.jpg", img)
    #apply threshold to get image with only black and white
    img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSAIN_C,             
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
    cv2.imwrite("1.jpg", img)
    #recognize text with tesseract for python
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("1.jpg"))
    return result
    print(get_string("a.jpg"))
```

error is following.

```
 C:\python\python.exe C:/Users/rharmed/PycharmProjects/nike/crawler2_.py
        Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/rharmed/PycharmProjects/nike/crawler2_.py", line 26, in         
        <module>
    print(get_string("a.jpg"))
    File "C:/Users/rharmed/PycharmProjects/nike/crawler2_.py", line 15, in         
        get_string
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    TypeError: kernel data type = 19 is not supported
        [ INFO:0] Initialize OpenCL runtime...

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: src data type = 17 is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732836/typeerror-src-data-type-17-is-not-supported)

Comment: I cann't understand  about TypeError: src data type = 17 is not supported.
Would you like more detail explain?

Comment: Please read the linked question, it asks allmost exactly what you're asking and the answer will give you the answer you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your kernel is not of a valid datatype.

change

```
kernel = np.ones((1,1), np.unicode)
```

to

```
kernel = np.ones((1,1), np.uint8)
```