# OpenCV SVM, TypeError: samples data type = 17 is not supported

Tags: python, svm, opencv3.0

I am an intermediate programmer and I have recently working with Histograms of Oriented Gradient (HOG) and SVM on OpenCV. Unfortunately, I have been running across this Type Error no matter what I have done so far. I couldn't find an answer that could let me solve this problem.

My code is written in python below:

```
import cv2  
import numpy as np  
import glob  

neg = glob.glob('...')  
pos = glob.glob('...')  
trainingImages = []  
trainingLabels = []  

for img in neg[0:30]:  
    image = cv2.imread(img)  
    trainingImages.append(image)  
    trainingLabels.append(0)  

for img in pos[0:30]:  
    image = cv2.imread(img)  
    trainingImages.append(image)  
    trainingLabels.append(1)  

winSize = (800,600)  
blockSize = (200,150)  
blockStride = (100,75)  
cellSize = (100,75)  
nbins = 9  
derivAperture = 1  
winSigma = -1.  
histogramNormType = 0  
L2HysThreshold = 0.2  
gammaCorrection = 1  
nlevels = 64  
useSignedGradients = False  

hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor(winSize, blockSize, 
    blockStride, cellSize, nbins, 
    derivAperture, winSigma, histogramNormType
    , L2HysThreshold, gammaCorrection, nlevels, 
    useSignedGradients)  

trainingData = []  
for img in trainingImages:  
    descriptor = hog.compute(img)  
    trainingData.append(descriptor)  

svm = cv2.ml.SVM_create()  

svm.setType(cv2.ml.SVM_C_SVC)  
svm.setKernel(cv2.ml.SVM_RBF)  
svm.setC(12.5)  
svm.setGamma(0.50625)  

svm.trainAuto(np.array(trainingData), cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, np.array(trainingLabels))

svm.save("digits_svm_model.yml")
```

I keep running into the problem at 
svm.trainAuto(np.array(trainingData), cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, np.array(trainingLabels))
where I am consistently told that 'TypeError: samples data type = 17 is not supported'

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41741109/5008845

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: src data type = 17 is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732836/typeerror-src-data-type-17-is-not-supported)