# TypeError: mat data type = 17 is not supported, show IR data with realsense d435

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, realsense

I'm currently working with a d435 and I want to display IR images (both left and right but for the moments just focus on one), following my code:

```
import pyrealsense2 as rs
import numpy as np
import cv2

# We want the points object to be persistent so we can display the 
#last cloud when a frame drops
points = rs.points()

# Create a pipeline
pipeline = rs.pipeline()
#Create a config and configure the pipeline to stream
config = rs.config()
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.infrared, 1, 1280, 720, rs.format.y8, 30)
# Start streaming
profile = pipeline.start(config)

# Streaming loop
try:
    while True:
        # Get frameset of color and depth
        frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
        ir1_frame = frames.get_infrared_frame(1) # Left IR Camera, it allows 1, 2 or no input
        image = np.asanyarray(ir1_frame)
        cv2.namedWindow('IR Example', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
        cv2.imshow('IR Example', image)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        # Press esc or 'q' to close the image window
        if key & 0xFF == ord('q') or key == 27:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
finally:
    pipeline.stop()
```

Everything works fine till the line:

```
cv2.imshow('IR Example', image)
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: mat data type = 17 is not supported

I found this link:
[TypeError: src data type = 17 is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732836/typeerror-src-data-type-17-is-not-supported)

but I still can't figure out how to show my image.
Does anyone have some ideas? Please share, i'm a newbie with opencv.

```
image.shape = ()
image.dtype = dtype('O')
```

Cheers

Comment: You could try changing the dtype from "object" to whatever it should be, maybe `image.astype(numpy.float32)` or something similar...

Comment: I think the problem is your image is type `np.int8` but needs to be `np.uint8`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `get_data()` to get the image from the frame.

```
image = np.asanyarray(ir1_frame.get_data())
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot by forgetting such an easy thing!^^

Comment: Don't!  Like you said, searching for the error didn't bring up relevant results.