# Append multiple training data npy files to one npy file

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have many .npy files which contain in the first column images, and in the second column another list which is a choice ([1,0,0] or [0,1,0] or [0,0,1]). I've saved every 50 frames - with their corresponding choices into .npy files, now when I train to append them all to one .npy file and save it, then try a for loop to run on the new .npy file in order to see the images (for debugging purposes - to see if it worked), it throws an error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-8-24f0dc711e53>", line 6, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('test', img)

TypeError: mat data type = 17 is not supported
```

Here's my merging code:

```
starting_value = 1;
train_data = np.load('training_data-{}.npy'.format(starting_value))
train_data_arr = []

# Merge all our training data files into one file
def merge_training_data():
    # load training data from pc
    while True:
        file_name = 'training_data-{}.npy'.format(starting_value)
        if os.path.isfile(file_name):
            train_data_arr.append(np.load(file_name))
            starting_value += 1
        else:
            print('File does not exist, finished merging!',starting_value)
            train_data_arr = np.array(train_data_arr)
            np.save(file_name, train_data_arr)
            break
```

And my testing:

```
#testing
starting_value = 4;
train_data = np.load('training_data-{}.npy'.format(starting_value))            
for data in train_data:
    img = data[0]
    choice = data[1]
    cv2.imshow('test', img)
    print(choice)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

My var explorer if the helps:
[image]

Comment: When you say "images" - what precisely do you mean? How are they stored? 
Does your testing code work if you load one of the "unmerged" training data files?

Comment: Take a look at this, it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732836/typeerror-src-data-type-17-is-not-supported

Answer (score 0):

The error is based on the image format you are using. Here is a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732836/typeerror-src-data-type-17-is-not-supported).

> You can find a list of OpenCV types here. type = 17 means that your
>   image is a CV_8SC3, aka a 3 channel matrix of char. However, threshold
>   accepts only  (single-channel, 8-bit or 32-bit floating point). which
>   means that the type must be either CV_8UC1 or CV_32FC1. Check shape
>   and dtype of your img, and adjust img as required.

I have also seen similar errors because it expects `mat` format but you aren't reading it to `mat` first, which may cause it to assume the `dtype` is `17` from your error when in reality the type is correct you just need to read the img before showing it.

Try this:

```
#testing
starting_value = 4;
train_data = np.load('training_data-{}.npy'.format(starting_value))            
for data in train_data:
    img = cv2.imread(data[0])
    choice = data[1]
    cv2.imshow('test', img)
    print(choice)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

It may be that when you saved these images they were in the correct format but have lost their class after being reloaded, so you need to tell Python what they are before you use them.